# pandas groupby and compare multiple columns and rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, compare

I have a `csv` with over 600 columns and thousands of rows. The original file contains more customers and departments, but this [example](https://pastebin.com/eCVaRWc9) includes the critical pieces.

*Note: I derived the `Site` column from `A_Loc1` and `B_Loc1` columns, in order to more easily compare and group the rows, but this is not a requirement. If the groupby can be performed without this, I am open to other approaches.*

I need to compare dates from different rows and columns, based on the `Cust_ID` and `Site`. So for example, confirm `A_Date1` is less than `B_Date1`, but only for the same `Cust_ID` and `Site` value.

So for `Cust_ID` `100` and `Site` `CA2.2`, `A_Date1` is `8/1/2015` and `B_Date1` is `6/15/2018`:

```
if A_Date1 > B_Date1:
     df['Result'] = "Fail"
 else:
     result = ""
```

In the above case, no action is needed because `A_Date1` is less than `B_Date1`.

However, for `Cust_ID` `100` and `Site` `CA2.0`, the `A_Date1` is `7/1/2019` and `B_Date1` is `12/15/2018`, so the `Result` column should be `Fail` for `Dep B` rows where `Site` is `CA2.0`.

I am open to performing this with any efficient, flexible approach, however, there are other comparisons I will need to perform with different rows and columns, but this should get me started.

**Expected Results:**

```
+----+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
|    | Result   |   Cust_ID | Dep   |   Order_Num | Site   | Rec_Date1   | Rec_DateX   | A_Date1   | A_Loc1   | A_DateX   | B_Loc1   | B_Date1    | B_Date2    | B_DateX   | C_Date1    | C_Loc1   | C_DateX   |
|----+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------|
|  0 |          |       100 | A     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             | 8/1/2015  | CA2.2    |           |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
|  1 |          |       100 | A     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             | 7/1/2019  | CA2.0    | 8/21/2019 |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
|  2 |          |       100 | B     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.2    | 6/15/2018  | 6/15/2016  | 8/1/2019  |            |          |           |
|  3 | Fail     |       100 | B     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.0    | 12/15/2018 | 12/15/2016 |           |            |          |           |
|  4 | Fail     |       100 | B     |           3 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.0    | 12/15/2018 | 12/15/2016 | 8/21/2019 |            |          |           |
|  5 |          |       100 | C     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             |           |          |           |          |            |            |           | 6/15/2016  | CA2.2    |           |
|  6 |          |       100 | C     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           |          |            |            |           | 12/15/2017 | CA2.0    | 8/21/2019 |
|  7 |          |       100 | Rec   |             |        | 6/12/2019   | 8/1/2019    |           |          |           |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
|  8 |          |       200 | A     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             | 8/1/2015  | CA2.2    |           |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
|  9 |          |       200 | A     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             | 7/1/2015  | CA2.0    | 8/21/2019 |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
| 10 |          |       200 | B     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.2    | 6/15/2018  | 6/15/2016  | 8/1/2019  |            |          |           |
| 11 |          |       200 | B     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.0    | 12/15/2018 | 12/15/2016 |           |            |          |           |
| 12 |          |       200 | B     |           3 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           | CA2.0    | 12/15/2018 | 12/15/2016 | 8/21/2019 |            |          |           |
| 13 |          |       200 | C     |           1 | CA2.2  |             |             |           |          |           |          |            |            |           | 6/15/2016  | CA2.2    |           |
| 14 |          |       200 | C     |           2 | CA2.0  |             |             |           |          |           |          |            |            |           | 12/15/2017 | CA2.0    | 8/21/2019 |
| 15 |          |       200 | Rec   |             |        | 6/12/2019   | 8/1/2019    |           |          |           |          |            |            |           |            |          |           |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

**What I've tried:**

```
# Returns: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
df['Result'] = df.loc[df.A_Date1 < df.B_Date1].groupby(['Cust_ID','Site'],as_index=False)

# Returns: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
df["Result"] = df.loc[(((df["A_Date1"] != "N/A") 
               & (df["B_Date1"] != "N/A"))
               & (df.A_Date1 < df.B_Date1))].groupby([
               'Cust_ID','Site'],as_index=False)

# Returns: ValueError: unknown type str224
conditions = "(x['A_Date1'].notna()) & (x['B_Date1'].notna()) & (x['A_Date1'] < x['B_Date1'])"
df["Result"] = df.groupby(['Cust_ID','Site']).apply(lambda x: pd.eval(conditions))

# TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
df = df[df.Dep != 'Rec']
df['Result'] = df.groupby(['Cust_ID','Site'],as_index = False).apply(lambda x: (x['A_Date1'].notna()) & (x['B_Date1'].notna()) & (x['A_Date1'] < x['B_Date1']))

# This produces FALSE for all rows
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Cust_ID','Site']).apply(lambda x: (x['A_Date1'].notna()) & (x['B_Date1'].notna()) & (x['A_Date1'] < x['B_Date1']))
```

**Update:**

I've figured out the solution for these two specific columns (`A_Loc1` and `B_Loc1`). First by converting these columns to `datetime`, adding the `Result` column, grouping and performing the comparison.

However, I have approximately 50 columns in my original file I need to compare. It would be ideal to iterate over a list of columns (or dictionary) to perform these steps.

```
## Solution for A_Loc1 and B_Loc1
## Convert all date columns to datetime, replace with NaN if error
df['A_Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A_Date1'], errors ="coerce")
df['B_Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B_Date1'], errors ="coerce")

# Add Result column
df.insert(loc=0, column="Result", value=np.nan)

# groupby Cust_ID and Site, then fill A_Date1 forward and back 
df['A_Date1'] = df.groupby(['Cust_ID','Site'], sort=False)['A_Date1'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

# Perform comparison
df.loc[(((df["A_Date1"].notna()) & (df["B_Date1"].notna()))
        & ((df["A_Date1"]) > (df["B_Date1"]))), 
       "Result"] = "Fail"
```

Comment: For Cust_ID 100 and Site CA2.2, how do you get B_Date1 as 7/1/2019? Isn't that the date for site CA2.0, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Dan, thanks. That was a typo. Just corrected it.

Comment: waht do you mean by 50 columns?

Comment: @Ben.T, as I mentioned I have other comparisons I need to perform. Instead of writing out all of the columns, I am looking for an efficient approach.

Comment: @m8_  got this part, but do you mean by other comparisons, still between dates, and the names of the columns have a pattern?

Comment: @Ben.T, yes, still dates and no pattern between header names. I was just giving so it was clear I was going to expand upon whatever solution was given. If a solution could reference a list/dict of header names, that would be ideal. If that is out of the scope of my question, please ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to post this solution with the hope of finding a more elegant and scalable implementation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

data = [[100,'A','1','','','8/1/2015','CA2.2','','','','','','','',''],
        [100,'A','2','','','7/1/2019','CA2.0','8/21/2019','','','','','','',''],
        [100,'B','1','','','','','','CA2.2','6/15/2018','6/15/2016','8/1/2019','','',''],
        [100,'B','2','','','','','','CA2.0','12/15/2018','12/15/2016','','','',''],       
        [100,'B','3','','','','','','CA2.0','12/15/2018','12/15/2016','8/21/2019','','',''],
        [100,'C','1','','','','','','','','','','6/15/2016','CA2.2',''],
        [100,'C','2','','','','','','','','','','12/15/2017','CA2.0','8/21/2019'],
        [100,'Rec','','6/12/2019','8/1/2019','','','','','','','','','',''],
        [200,'A','1','','','8/1/2015','CA2.2','','','','','','','',''],
        [200,'A','2','','','7/1/2015','CA2.0','8/21/2019','','','','','','',''],
        [200,'B','1','','','','','','CA2.2','6/15/2018','6/15/2016','8/1/2019','','',''],
        [200,'B','2','','','','','','CA2.0','12/15/2018','12/15/2016','','','',''],       
        [200,'B','3','','','','','','CA2.0','12/15/2018','12/15/2016','8/21/2019','','',''],
        [200,'C','1','','','','','','','','','','6/15/2016','CA2.2',''],
        [200,'C','2','','','','','','','','','','12/15/2017','CA2.0','8/21/2019'],
        [200,'Rec','','6/12/2019','8/1/2019','','','','','','','','','','']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Cust_ID','Dep','Order_Num','Rec_Date1',
                                'Rec_DateX','A_Date1','A_Loc1','A_DateX',
                                'B_Loc1','B_Date1','B_Date2','B_DateX',
                                'C_Date1','C_Loc1','C_DateX'])

# replace blanks with np.NaN
df.replace(r"^s*$", np.nan, regex=True, inplace = True)

## Convert all date columns to datetime, replace with NaN if error
df['A_Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A_Date1'], errors ="coerce")
df['B_Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B_Date1'], errors ="coerce")


# Add Site and Result column
df.insert(loc=4, column="Site", value=np.nan)
df.insert(loc=0, column="Result", value=np.nan)

# Populate Site column based on related column
df.loc[df["A_Loc1"].notna(), 
       "Site"] = df["A_Loc1"]

df.loc[df["B_Loc1"].notna(), 
       "Site"] = df["B_Loc1"]

df.loc[df["C_Loc1"].notna(), 
       "Site"] = df["C_Loc1"]

# groupby Cust_ID and Site, and fill A_Date1 forward and back
df['A_Date1'] = df.groupby(['Cust_ID','Site'], sort=False)['A_Date1'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

# Perform comparison
df.loc[(((df["A_Date1"].notna()) & (df["B_Date1"].notna()))
        & ((df["A_Date1"]) > (df["B_Date1"]))), 
       "Result"] = "Fail"
```